# Links and on click in ListView?

Tags: java, android

i used `android:autoLink="web"` in textview inside a listView, the problem when the listview have a link, it looks like the `android:autoLink="web`" override the on click function for that listview .
What i need is to be able to click the link and able to click on the listview that contains the link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not solution for the problem but its different way to handle it in my App, when ever the user click to the ListView it will go to another activity that shows the text with the link and then the user can click their , this is what i found most of twitter feeds do,  like Seesmic App on Android.

Answer (score 0):

use Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);

Comment: it didnt work , i still cant click on the listview if there's link on it , thanks for the answer though.

Comment: ah yeah i ran into this issue as well.  i misread your original question.  I don't believe you can do this. (though i'd love to be proven wrong).  Have you considered using a long click for each row instead of a normal click?

Comment: i think so too , some how they override each other. i thought of creating long press, then i let the user go to more details screen there he can click the links . 
thanks for following this with me :)